# occasional slow UPDATE using primary key

Tags: mysql, query-cache

I have an InnoDB table in MySQL 5.5.53 where simple updates like

```
UPDATE mytable SET acol = 'value' WHERE id = 42;
```

hang for several seconds. `id` is the primary key of the table.

If I enable query profiling using

```
SET profiling = 1;
```

then run the query and look at the profile, I see something like:

```
show profile;
+------------------------------+----------+
| Status                       | Duration |
+------------------------------+----------+
| starting                     | 0.000077 |
| checking permissions         | 0.000008 |
| Opening tables               | 0.000024 |
| System lock                  | 0.000008 |
| init                         | 0.000346 |
| Updating                     | 0.000108 |
| end                          | 0.000004 |
| Waiting for query cache lock | 0.000002 |
| end                          | 3.616845 |
| query end                    | 0.000016 |
| closing tables               | 0.000015 |
| freeing items                | 0.000023 |
| logging slow query           | 0.000003 |
| logging slow query           | 0.000048 |
| cleaning up                  | 0.000004 |
+------------------------------+----------+
```

That is, all the time is spent in `end`.

[The documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/general-thread-states.html) says:

> - `end`
>
>   This occurs at the end but before the cleanup of `ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE VIEW`, `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `SELECT`, or `UPDATE` statements.

How can such a simple statement spend such a long time in this state?

Comment: I am curious to know how many rows do you have in this table. and also do you have more updates/inserts/deletes or more selects in the application using this table?

Comment: Around 300000 rows, and I don't know the read/write ratio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is the query cache.

If I disable it with

```
SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 0;
SET GLOBAL query_cache_type = 0;
```

the problem goes away.

It must be invalidating query cache entries that causes the query to hang for such a long time.